# Protocols equivalent to TLS?

Tags: tls

Are there any protocols equivalent to TLS that are widely used, or the TLS is the most, worldwide used protocol to secure almost all the traffic available in the network?

Comment: SSH can be a potential alternative depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague.  TLS is used with a protocol to enable encryption on the protocol itself; such as HTTP -> HTTPS, SMTP -> SMTPS.   It adds a layer of security through confidentiality and authenticity.

To "secure all traffic", you'd probably need something like a VPN tunnel.  This way, all traffic -both encrypted and unencrypted- are tunneled through an encrypted, authenticated tunnel, and you don't have to bother about enabling encryption for each protocol.  An eavesdropper will just see encrypted data between two nodes.